# The mystery number '63' in the context of demand paging

Tags: c, memory-management, virtual-memory, page-replacement

I am running a code that mimics demand paging system here are some of the parameters:

```
Page size = 4096 bits
Processor = 32 bits
Number of page frames = (variable)
```

I run my code with a fifo or random page replacement algorithm with number of page frames set to 100. My disk read/ write ends at 63.

Then when I changed the Processor size to 32 bits - this boundary moves to 16.

The latter case, I understand. If the page frame count is more than the possible page table entries,  (2^4) there is no need for evictions.

But I don't understand **why in the former case, where the page table entries go up to 2^20, the disk read/write stops at 63 with both page replacement algorithms**.

What is this mystery 63 number? Any idea where this may be coming from? Thank you.

Comment: If you counting disk I/O as simulated by code you run, why not assume it's just a bug in that code? If you counting actual OS-level I/O -- what is your OS?

Comment: @Victor I am counting the code level I/O. I understand there is a bug in the code. I am trying to figure out where it may be coming from - logic or syntax. First, I am trying to rule out the logical flaw.

Comment: the only interesting thing I can say about 63 here -- it's 2^6 - 1 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference string had only 63 pages -- now that I have gotten some sleep...